# Black background behind image in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-resources

Seems silly but I have tried using ImageButton, Image view but the black square behind circular image is not going. I am using png image and want transparent background.

I have attached the expected output, layout view in android and real device but look very different and nothing seems to work

Expected result
[image: What I want]

Actual result
[image: Device screen shot]

Drawable Resource Image[image: resource file]

Edited Code XML Layout. Reset other views are fine

Layout Image
[image: Layout]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.fragments.DashboardFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_dashboard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guide_horizontal_30"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<!-- background image resource -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFromDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/from_date"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_dashboard" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFromDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10dp"
        android:text="Date"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dashboard_bottom_blue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guide_vertical_40"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtFromDate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFromDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtToDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5dp"
        android:text="@string/to_date"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/txtFromDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guide_vertical_40" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvToDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tvFromDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guide_vertical_80"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtToDate" />

<!-- problematic image view-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnGo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_search"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvToDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guide_vertical_80"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtToDate" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What is background of the parent view, which has your `ImageView`? Can you post complete/related layout?

Comment: Check the edited question

Comment: I didn't understand the image which you posted kind of screenshot or something in that there is no black background behind that search icon.

Comment: the image is from xml layout.  Yes i know there is no black background behind the image still it is showing that's why i am confused

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say it doesn't show black background in layout preview but does show in device? Did you try with simple ImageView as well? And is device having dark mode?

Comment: Yes not showing black background in preview. I have used ImageView as well but nothing is changing. Theme of the activity which has this fragment is AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: I think you can try giving some background color to image view and some other color to parent view and see which color it picks.

Comment: nothing is changing i have given white background to parent container as well as background to image view

Comment: Quite strange. I cannot write it at my end to reproduce it so can't say much. May be you can try using same drawable in some other simple layout like LinearLayout or some other project to understand whats happening.

Comment: i have used the same image view at the end of the layout it is working fine but i dont  know what is happening there. black background is only behind the same location not behind others in the same layout

Answer (score 0):

use this if you don't want black background just remove background from layout.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/btn_key"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:src="@drawable/img_key"
    />
```

Comment: No changes in the layout. Still there is black background

Comment: check @drawable/bg_dashboard , you are using black background or not

Comment: no it is a image and not of black color here for posting it, i have overlapped it with black color

Comment: give a white background in constraint layout, what is the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206715/discussion-between-avinash-and-amanpreet-kaur).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my image and what I just did is to change the Background of the imageView and make it Transparent.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_dashboard"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guide_horizontal_30"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```